# Making a reactive global variable in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, ggvis

I want to append some text to a panel below a ggvis plot when the user clicks (tooltip) on an object.  This is in addition to a hover message from a separate tooltip.  As it stands:

**server.R**

```
require(ggvis); require(shiny)

pet_rep <<- ''

tooltip_headline = function(x) "Headline detail. Click to open full detail below"

tooltip_values = function(x){
  pet_rep <<- sample(LETTERS, 26) %>% paste(collapse=' ')
  return(pet_rep)
}

function(input, output, session) {
  output$petreport = renderUI({HTML(paste0('<h1>', pet_rep, '</h1>'))})
  observe({
    ggvis(mtcars, ~disp, ~mpg) %>% layer_points() %>%
      add_tooltip(tooltip_headline, 'hover') %>%
      add_tooltip(tooltip_values, 'click') %>% 
      bind_shiny('ggvis_plot', 'ggvis_ui')
  })
}
```

**ui.R**

```
require(ggvis); require(shiny)

fluidPage(
  makeReactiveBinding("pet_rep"),
  uiOutput("ggvis_ui"), ggvisOutput("ggvis_plot"),
  uiOutput('petreport')
)
```

As far as I can tell this should work via a `runApp()` call, but I find the text doesn't reliably (at least when server first runs it) appear in the panel below the plot, and if on subsequent page calls it does appear it doesn't refresh on new clicks.  [This shinyapps.io app demonstrates.](https://geotheory.shinyapps.io/test/)

The code *does* however work when run interactively in RStudio in a single script using the `shinyApp(ui, server)` approach.  But I cannot get the `runApp()` execution approach to work that is necessary for hosting on shinyapps.io.  Most grateful for assistance.

Comment: For future readers: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70756822/9841389) you can find a related post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK so the following does work on `shinyapps.io` (i.e. single file approach with `app.R`):

**app.R**

```
require(ggvis); require(shiny)

pet_rep <<- ''

tooltip_headline = function(x) "Headline detail. Click to open full detail below"

tooltip_values = function(x){
  pet_rep <<- sample(LETTERS, 26) %>% paste(collapse=' ')
  return(pet_rep)
}

server = function(input, output, session) {
  output$petreport = renderUI({HTML(paste0('<h1>', pet_rep, '</h1>'))})
  observe({
    ggvis(mtcars, ~disp, ~mpg) %>% layer_points() %>%
      add_tooltip(tooltip_headline, 'hover') %>%
      add_tooltip(tooltip_values, 'click') %>% 
      bind_shiny('ggvis_plot', 'ggvis_ui')
  })
}

ui = fluidPage(
  makeReactiveBinding("pet_rep"),
  uiOutput("ggvis_ui"), ggvisOutput("ggvis_plot"),
  uiOutput('petreport')
)

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

Im not 100% what you want but is this it?

```
require(ggvis); require(shiny)
pet_rep <<- ''
tooltip_headline = function(x) "Headline detail. Click to open full detail below"
tooltip_values = function(x){
  pet_rep <<- sample(LETTERS, 26) %>% paste(collapse=' ')
  return(pet_rep)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("ggvis_ui"), 
  ggvisOutput("ggvis_plot"),
  uiOutput('petreport')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observe({
    makeReactiveBinding("pet_rep")
  })

  output$petreport = renderUI({
    HTML(paste0('<h1>', pet_rep, '</h1>'))})

  ggvis(mtcars, ~disp, ~mpg) %>% layer_points() %>%
    add_tooltip(tooltip_headline, 'hover') %>%
    add_tooltip(tooltip_values, 'click') %>% 
    bind_shiny('ggvis_plot', 'ggvis_ui')

}

runApp(shinyApp(ui, server), launch.browser = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Mr/Mrs Chop, can you possibly confirm if this runs properly for you? i.e. is the panel properly reactive?  For me this only works when you redirect a browser to an instance for the second time, and then it's not reactive.