# Sharing reactive data sets between user sessions in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, global-variables, polling, bigdata

I have a fairly large reactive data set that is derived from polling a file and then reading that file on a predefined interval.  The data is updated frequently and requires constant reloading.  Admittedly, the reloading could be done incrementally and appended to the existing object in R, but isn't.  However currently, this action is done for each user of the shiny app although the data is the same across sessions.

The only way I have come up with a round about solution was to determine if the session is the first, and have that session be the master for updating the data through polling.  The subsequent sessions don't poll provided there is still a `master`.

Is there an easier way to accomplish the same result without handling this master relationship?

It's almost like a need a reactive call inside of the global function that works on behalf of all clients/sessions.

Answer (score 2):

I hope I understood the question. I am assuming that the data set is same for all sessions and all connections. I.e.: if one user updates the data set, it should be updated for all other sessions as well? If that is the case, I would just simply read from a database and write to that database every time some user updates it. If you have a MySQL database, you can use that. Alternatively you can use an app-specific SQLite database file in your application and you can keep it together with your `server.r` and `ui.r` files and all other app-specific files.

You can still read from the database on a predefined interval. This way you don't keep a copy of the data in RAM and avoid loading it multiple times for each Shiny session.

Another option might be this.
Furthermore, in your `server.r` file, anything you put INside your `shinyServer()` function will run each time a session is created (i.e. each time a user points their browser to your app). Anything you put OUTside your `shinyServer()` function (e.g. at the very beginning) will only run once at the initialization of your app on `runApp()` command. So if you load your data set once OUTside of your `shinyServer()` function and save it to a global environment variable, than it should be accessible by all sessions. Each session would need to re-save it to global environment as well.

`assign("main_df", df, envir = .GlobalEnv)`

Comment: All good suggestions.  Can one assign a global reactive variable outside of `shinyServer()`?  I believe I have tried that before without success.  I will test that again.  It is almost like I need polling / updating of the data set outside of `shinyServer()` and updating a global reactive variable so when that data changes globally, each user's view is updated.

Comment: You are right, you cannot create a _reactive_ variable outside of `shinyServer()` but you can create a variable in global R environment, which will be accessible from any function and/or loop, as well as your Shiny server and reactive functions. More on environments in R here: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/environment.html But I would first try the database option. Why don't you create a database either MySQL or SQLite, as I suggested previously? This way the application will be scalable, as dataframe will not need to load into the app entirely and will not use RAM

Comment: I was investigating on a similar issue and came across this excellent post. I have a reverse problem. I suspect two user sessions for the same app.R are having some clashes as the app frequently disconnects at random points for all users. As I use several global variables, it might be the reason of the crash. Is it true that the global variables (outside server() ) but inside app.R are shared across sessions? What if I do not want them to be shared? If this is completely different question I will create one. Just let me know @KirillSavine

Comment: yes same as if they were defined in `global.r` file. Those variables are shared by all active shiny sessions sharing the same R session.

Answer (score 0):

The scenario you describe perfectly fits `reactiveFileReader()`:

There even is an example `cross-session reactive file reader` on the help page `?reactiveFileReader`:

> Cross-session reactive file reader. In this example, all sessions
> share the same reader, so read.csv only gets executed once no matter
> how many user sessions are connected.

```
fileData <- reactiveFileReader(1000, session = NULL, 'data.csv', read.csv)
function(input, output, session) {
  output$data <- renderTable({
    fileData()
  })
```

Note the `session = NULL` argument. In this context also check `reactivePoll()` - both have to be placed in the **global part** of the app to work across sessions.

---

**Alternative:**

Furthermore it is possible to create cross-session `reactiveValues` - just create them outside the server function (global).
Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47731177/9841389) or [this](https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/chat-room.html) for examples.

In the following example only one active session is allowed to update the global `reactiveValues` (which I posted [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/cross-session-global-reactive-reactivepoll/126737/2) first) - this can be advantageous when running computationally intensive code:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(textOutput("time"))

rv <- reactiveValues() # global reactiveValues

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  isolate(rv$active_sessions <- c(rv$active_sessions, session$token))
  
  observe({
    invalidateLater(2000)
    if(rv$active_sessions[1] == session$token){
      print(paste(as.character(Sys.time()), "session:", session$token))
      rv$current_time <- as.character(Sys.time())
    }
  })
  
  output$time <- renderText(rv$current_time)
  
  onSessionEnded(fun = function(){
    isolate(rv$active_sessions <- setdiff(rv$active_sessions, session$token))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```