# How to run a scheduled cross-session database query in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I have an Oracle database which is refreshed once a day.  I am a bit confused on how apps work in Shiny, what gets run once on app startup - and what gets run once per session.

My naive approach was to create a database connection and run a query outside of UI and Server code to create a dataframe of around 600,000 records...which can then be filtered and sliced during the session.  I am a bit concerned by doing it inside app.R in global scope, that this connection and dataframe will only be created once when the server starts the app, and will never get run again (if that makes sense).

If I create the data frame in server, then my UI code fails, as is is dependent on the results of a query to populate the select list, and I do this in app.R scope at the moment, so UI can access it.

```
library(shiny)
library(DBI)
library(dplyr)
library(odbc)
library(stringdist)
library(reactable)

############################################################################
# business functions                                                       #
############################################################################
get_list_of_actives_from_db <- function() {
  con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), Driver="oracle", Host = "server.mycompany.net", Port = "1521", SVC = "service1", UID = "user_01", PWD = "hello", timeout = 10)
  
  ingredients_df = dbGetQuery(con,
                        '
      select DISTINCT INGREDIENTS FROM AES
    '
  )      
}

get_adverse_events_from_db <- function() {
  con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), Driver="oracle", Host = "server.mycompany.net", Port = "1521", SVC = "service1", UID = "user_01", PWD = "hello", timeout = 10)
  
  cases_df = dbGetQuery(con,
    '
      select * FROM AES
    '
  )
  
  return(cases_df)
}

############################################################################
# load data sets for use in dashboard                                      #
############################################################################


cases_df = get_adverse_events_from_db()          # drive select list in UI
ingredients_df = get_list_of_actives_from_db()   # main data to slice and filter


############################################################################
# shiny UI                                                                 #
############################################################################


ui <- fluidPage(
  "Adverse Event Fuzzy Search Tool",
  
  fluidRow(
    selectInput("ingredients", label = "Select on or more Active Ingredients:", choices = ingredients_df$PRIMARY_SUSPECT_KEY_INGREDIENT, multi=TRUE),
  
    textInput("search_term", "AE Search Term:"),
  
    actionButton("do_search", "Perform Search")
  )
  ,
  fluidRow(
    reactableOutput("search_results")
  )
)


 

############################################################################
# shiny server                                                             #
############################################################################

server <- function(input, output, session) {
     # do stuff here to filter the data frame based on the selected value and render a table      
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

My main concern is doing this in the root of app.R, both functions run oracle queries which never need to be re-run for the session, as the data will only change overnight via ETL.

```
############################################################################
# load data sets for use in dashboard                                      #
############################################################################
cases_df = get_adverse_events_from_db()
ingredients_df = get_list_of_actives_from_db()
```

When and how often is this called?  Once when the app is initialized so the data set is never updated and is shared across sessions by users?  Or is the entire script run end to end whenever a new sessions is started?

Part of me thinks it should be in the server function, so it runs once per session.  But being new to Shiny I feel like server is called constantly whenever there is a change in the UI, I dont want to be constantly loading 600,000 records from Oracle.

Ideally I would cache the results once a day and make them available to all users across all sessions, not sure how to achieve that - so for now just want to know the best way to achieve this, so each user runs the query once and has the data frame cached for the session.

Comment: Maybe you can run a cron job outside of shiny once a day that creates the data.frame which is then used by the app? Otherwise, you can always create a `reactiveVal` once per session that reads in the DB, so it does not get rerun when you change the filtering criteria. Apart from that, I recommend to look at [`pool`](https://rstudio.github.io/pool/) to manage the DB connections.

Comment: I don't see how `pool`-ing the database connection will help with data invalidation and req-query. @starja, am I missing a connection?

Comment: @starja I am using the results of a query to drive a select list in the UI, can I still use a reactiveVal here and have it update the UI once per session with the correct drop down values?  I have ended up down the rabbit hole of looking at renderUI and uiOutput

Comment: @r2evans sorry if this didn't come across, I meant the reference to pool as a general note for good practise and not especially for the invalidation/re-query part

Comment: @smackenzie yes, you can by initialising the `selectInput` with no choices and then using `updateSelectInput` in the `server` part once the reactiveVal is loaded.

Comment: I see, thanks @starja. I've found the use of `pool` to be good in one sense, but especially when considering asynchronous work (e.g., `future`), a `pool` object is a liability (similar to a regular `con`nection object, to be honest), since it cannot be transferred between processes. For that, with exceptions I mostly create the connection at the time of query and immediately close it. I have fixed countless instability/bugs using this technique.

Comment: @starja thanks, am I right in assuming if I load my data frame in Server, it will only get run once at session startup?

Comment: @smackenzie as far as I know, yes. If you read it into a `reactive` you just have to make sure that it does not get invalidated by some user input, but if you just read it in from the DB there shouldn't be any problem

Comment: @starja if it doesn’t tie to an input, will it ever get executed?!

Comment: `reactiveValues`/`reactive`/`reactiveVal` and normal variables are initialised at startup

Comment: @r2evans just a comment on the `pool` package + futures discussion: I'm using a pool object only in the main process. Once a child process (or future) is started I create a new db connection for this process based on the connection details provided by the parent process via `dbConnect`. This works reliably and avoids quite a bunch of connect/disconnect cycles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check RStudio's article [Scoping rules for Shiny apps](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/scoping.html) in this context.

If I got you right, you are asking to share a dataset across shiny-sessions and update it daily (The title of the question didn't really fit your explanation of the problem - I edited it).

I'd suggest using a cross-session `reactivePoll` to avoid unnecessary DB queries (I once asked a similar question [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/cross-session-global-reactive-reactivepoll/126737) - Over there I gave an example showing, that the same can be [achived via reactiveValues](https://community.rstudio.com/t/cross-session-global-reactive-reactivepoll/126737/2) but it's more complex).

Here is the simple pattern you can use - please note that `reactivePoll` is defined outside the server function so all sessions share the same data:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(textOutput("my_db_data"))

updated_db_data <- reactivePoll(
  intervalMillis = 1000L*60L*5L, # check for a new day every 5 minutes
  session = NULL,
  checkFunc = function() {
    print(paste("Running checkFunc:", Sys.time()))
    Sys.Date()
  },
  valueFunc = function() {
    # your db query goes here:
    paste("Latests DB update:", Sys.time())
  }
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$my_db_data <- renderText(updated_db_data())
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Here, every 5 minutes the `checkFunc` checks for a new day - `valueFunc` is executed only if the result of `checkFunc` changed. As a (real world) alternative for `checkFunc` you could implement a query to **check for the number of rows of a certain DB table**.

PS: There is an example given on a cross-session `reactiveFileReader` (which is based on `reactivePoll`) when viewing `?reactiveFileReader`

PPS: When doing further filtering etc. on that dataset also check [bindCache()](https://rdrr.io/github/rstudio/shiny/man/bindCache.html).

Comment: Thanks, what aspect of this makes the result of the query shared across sessions?

Comment: As mentioned above the `reactivePoll()` function needs to be defined outside the server function - also note its parameter `session = NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

While untested, perhaps this architecture will work:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  dailydata_ <- reactiveValues(when = NULL, what = NULL)

  dailydata <- reactive({
    oldwhen <- dailydata_$when
    if (is.null(oldwhen) ||
          as.Date(oldwhen) < Sys.Date()) {
      newdata <- tryCatch(
        DBI::dbGetQuery(con, "..."),
        error = function(e) e)
      if (inherits(newdata, "error")) {
        warning("error retrieving new data: ", conditionMessage(e))
        warning("using stale data instead")
      } else {
        dailydata_$when <- Sys.time()
        dailydata_$what <- newdata
      }
    }
    dailydata_$what
  })

  # some consumer of the real data
  output$tbl <- renderTable(dailydata())

}
```

The advantage to this is that it's re-query will trigger when the data was retrieved on a different *day*. Granted, when the new ETL is available might change how exactly this conditional is fashioned, it might be that if it is updated at (say) 2am, then you may need some more time-math to determine if the current data is before or after the most recent update.

This logic has a "data available" fail: if it could not be queried, then the current/stale data is re-used. If you prefer that it returns no data, that is easy enough to change in the code.

(One thing you might want to do is to show the user when the data was last retrieved; this can be retrieved directly with `dailydata_$when`, accepting that it might be `NULL`.)

Comment: Thanks, will play tomorrow.  Plowing  through a shiny book to try and get a better grip

Comment: Maybe you could combine this with [initialising `dailydata_` outside of the `server` function in a global scope](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47731177/12647315), then it is shared between all sessions and the DB fetching is only done once per day. However, I don't know how stable/practical it is.

Comment: Yeah, there's certainly potential to pre-fill the cache, so-to-speak. Frankly, one could derive a function that always returns the cached (in memory) data unless the timestamp of the underlying file is before the refill time-of-day, but that's a little more information than we have. And ... as long as there is something that depends on `dailydata()`, the first user will pay a small penalty, all others are just fine.