# Refresh Shiny App when DataBase changes occur

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, pool

I deployed a shiny app to our company's AWS server. It serves as an internal dashboard. I recently found some articles about how to make the charts and tables refresh dynamically from the database every x milliseconds. However, this causes plots to be re-rendered every x milliseconds regardless of whether it is necessary or not. Aside from making the DashBoard jittery, I'm somewhat worried about the resource drain it might represent when the DashBoard will be full (about 60-100 plots). Is there a way that one can make the charts refresh whenever the table in the database that is being called changes?

Suppose the following dataframe is in the database:

```r
df = tibble(id = as.factor(c(1:10)),
            value = c(sample(c(1:50), 10, replace = TRUE)),
            variable = c(sample(c('blue','red','green'), 10, replace = TRUE)))
```

And the 'df' object now represents the pool connector to the database:

```r
renderPlot{(
  invalidateLater(10000)
  
  my plot = df %>% 
    ggplot(aes(id, value, color = variable)) +
    geom_point()
  
  myplot
)}
```

This plot will basically be re-rendered every 10 seconds, which causes the entire plot to refresh. What I would like is to instead check the database every 10 seconds, and re-render the plot only if the database table being called has changed. Any ideas?

Comment: Use a two stage process.  As a simple example, one data frame to represent the current state of the database, a second to provide data to display in the plot.  Interrogate the database as required to detect changes.  If and only if a change is detected, update the data source for the plot.

Comment: @Limey there is no need for two `data.frame`s or `reactive`s. This is a classical usecase for `reactivePoll`. From the docs: `reactivePoll works by pairing a relatively cheap "check" function with a more expensive value retrieval function.` The check function could e.g. monitor the number of rows of a DB table and new data is queried only after a change. Please see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73455786/9841389) for an example.

Comment: @ismirsehregal  I had forgotten about `reactivePoll`.  Thank you.  But we agree on the underlying process: first interrogate the database to see if changes have occured and then, if and only if changes are detcted, update the GUI.  I agree that the cheaper and quicker the initial interrogation, the better.

Comment: @Limey exactly - we need to do as little work as possible in shiny itself (including memory usage). Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below please find an example on how to detect updates of a database table using `reactivePoll`.

The upper part of the script starts a background R session and continuously writes data to a sqlite database (to illustrate a realstic scenario).

In the shiny app part I'm using a global `reactivePoll`, which provides an update to the displayed data once the row count of the monitored database table changed.

Observing the row count instead of a timestamp is advantageous because not every database table will provide you with a timestamp and more over you might need to deal with clock shifts of local daylight saving times instead of UTC.

However, to realize a chunked update of the table we need an extra `reactiveVal`:

```
library(DT)
library(DBI)
library(shiny)
library(callr)
library(RSQLite)
library(datasets)
library(data.table)

# create dummy data -------------------------------------------------------
bgprocess <- r_bg(func = function(){
  con <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), "iris_db.sqlite")
  on.exit(dbDisconnect(con))
  if(DBI::dbIsValid(con) && !DBI::dbExistsTable(con, "iris")){
    DBI::dbWriteTable(con, "iris", datasets::iris[1,])
  }
  for (i in 2:NROW(iris)){
    Sys.sleep(4)
    print("Updating DB")
    DBI::dbWriteTable(con, "iris", datasets::iris[i,], append = TRUE)
    if(i == NROW(datasets::iris)){
      print("Finished updating DB")
    }
  }
})

# bgprocess$is_alive()
print(paste("bgprocess pid:", bgprocess$get_pid()))


# shiny app ---------------------------------------------------------------
con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), "iris_db.sqlite")
row_count <- 0L
previous_row_count <- 0L
display_data <- reactiveVal(NULL)

ui <- fluidPage(DTOutput("my_db_data"))

db_data_chunk <- reactivePoll(
  intervalMillis = 1000L, # check for a db update every second
  session = NULL,
  checkFunc = function() {
    print(paste("Running checkFunc:", Sys.time()))
    if(DBI::dbIsValid(con) && dbExistsTable(con, "iris")){
      row_count <<- dbGetQuery(con, "select count(*) from iris")[[1]]
    } else {
      0L
    }
  },
  valueFunc = function() {
    if(DBI::dbIsValid(con) && dbExistsTable(con, "iris")){
      print(paste("Running valueFunc: Updating display_data | Current row count:", row_count))
      DT <- setDT(dbGetQuery(con, sprintf("select * from iris LIMIT %s OFFSET %s", row_count-previous_row_count, previous_row_count)))
      previous_row_count <<- row_count
      DT
    } else {
      NULL
    }
  }
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(db_data_chunk(), {
    if(is.null(display_data())){
      display_data(db_data_chunk())
    } else {
      display_data(rbindlist(list(display_data(), db_data_chunk())))
    }
  })
  # check ?dataTableProxy() and ?replaceData() to avoid re-rendering the table
  output$my_db_data <- renderDT({req(display_data())}, server = FALSE)
}

shinyApp(ui, server, onStart = function() {
  onStop(function() {
    dbDisconnect(con)
  })
})
```

Answer (score 3):

You can maybe do something like this, note that `data <- sendquery(query) # send the query to DB` is how you send the query to DB for new records, so adjust accordingly. Data will be shared across all sessions... You can use the `reactivePoll` also, but it will compare the entire dataset with the previous one before update, unless you get the last timestamp or something similar into the `checkFunc`, so the operation is small. Good example is provided by @ismirsehregal [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73450861/how-to-run-a-scheduled-cross-session-database-query-in-shiny/73455786#73455786). Its best to get the deltas (new records) from `Database` directly and use `R` for small things like displaying the data

```
library(shiny)
library(tibble)
library(ggplot2)

df <- tibble(id = as.factor(c(1:10)),
            value = c(sample(c(1:50), 10, replace = TRUE)),
            variable = c(sample(c('blue','red','green'), 10, replace = TRUE)))

autoInvalidate <- reactiveTimer(1000, session=NULL)
v <- reactiveValues(mytimestamp = Sys.time())
data <- NULL

new_data_check <- reactive({
  autoInvalidate()
  query <- 'select from table where timestamp > LASTTIMESTAMP'
  query <- gsub("LASTTIMESTAMP",v$mytimestamp,query)
  #data <- sendquery(query) # send the query to DB
  
  if(!is.null(data)){
    df <<- rbind(df,data)
    v$mytimestamp <- max(data$timestamp)
  }
})


ui <- fluidPage(
  plotOutput("myplot")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observe({
    new_data_check()
  })

  newdata <- eventReactive(v$mytimestamp,{
    df
  })

  output$myplot <- renderPlot({
    myplot <- df %>%
      ggplot(aes(id, value, color = variable)) +
      geom_point()
    myplot
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Your statement on `reactivePoll` is wrong. You don't have to compare the entire dataset. As written above you can e.g. compare the row count of a database table and use it as a trigger for the value retrieval function (which might fetch only new rows).

Comment: @ismirsehregal, you're right yes, if the check is small, then it should be fast, I updated my answer